# Combine two selectors with one jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have two divs with id's: `#addNew_tab` and `#sendCom_tab`.
I'd like clicking on either of these to trigger the same jQuery `click()` function.

I was thinking something like:

```
$("#addNew_tab", "#sendCom_tab").click(function(){
      //do stuff
});
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$("#addNew_tab, #sendCom_tab").click(function(){
      //do stuff
});
```

Changed from:

```
$("#addNew_tab", "#sendCom_tab")
```

To:

```
$("#addNew_tab, #sendCom_tab")
```

---

comma inside the selector(`"a, b")` means the first plus the second; Just like with CSS selectors
(Well, it's a CSS selector...)

> **jQuery(selector)**
>
> Description: Accepts a string containing a **CSS selector** which is then used to match a set of elements.

It's equal to:

```
$("#addNew_tab").add("#sendCom_tab")...
```

Comment: @ElliotBonneville it's the same way you would do with css without repeationg rules like `a, div { display: none; }`

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. It's just like `add`

Comment: cool, that did it. I knew it was something like that. Didn't think it could accept a comma in quotes but hey, learned something new. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, that's right, jQuery shares CSS handlers. Wow, that's quick the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doStuff() {
    // do stuff
}

$("#addNew_tab").click(doStuff);
$("#sendCom_tab").click(doStuff);
```