# How can I do OR in jquery for an element selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combine two selectors with one jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515888/combine-two-selectors-with-one-jquery-object)

I have the following jquery code:

```
  $("#try").click(function(){
  ...
```

If I click on `#try`, the browser executes the function. Suppose I want to add another element, `#try2`, that will execute the same function. How would I add an `or` to the above code? I've tried using,

```
  $("#try" or "#try2").click(function(){
  ...
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does 'click on try AND try2' means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ir you have only `try` and `try2` then you should go for

```
 $("#try, #try2").click(function(){
    // your code
 });
```

You can use comma separated multiple selector within `$()`

---

But if you have more then try

```
 $("[id^=try]").click(function(){
    // your code
 });
```

This will bind click event to those element which `id`s start with `try`, like `try` or `try1` or `try2` etc.

---

### According to comment

#### How can I detect clicked element's id

```
 $("#try, #donttry").click(function(){
    if(this.id == 'try') {
     // do something when try
    } else {
      // do something when donttry
    }
 });
```

**[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/161/)**

Comment: Okok, tnks u, work. And how can i make sure that when you click on "try" or "donttry", the browser run the code??

Comment: No its not going to work... this will only works for starts with try...

Answer (score 3):

Just separate them by a coma.

```
$( "#try, #try2" ).click( function() {
});
```