# How to hide elements defined as variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I have two variables defined as:

```
var div1 = $("#div1");

var div2 = $("#div2");
```

I know that I can use  `$("#div1, #div2").hide()` to hide both div

But is there a way I can hide them through defined variables like `(div1, div2).hide()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two selectors with one jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515888/combine-two-selectors-with-one-jquery-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add other elements to existing selector:

```
div1.add(div2).hide()
```

Comment: @NJason, The worse reason.

Answer (score 9):

You could use ***[.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)*** method:

```
div1.add(div2).hide();
```