# Iterate through an array of var chained variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have a simple function in javascript that hides all css divs on page load:

```
function hideAllDivs() {
    var a5 = jQuery('.a5'),
        a2 = jQuery('.a2'),
        b2 = jQuery('.b2'),
        hd3 = jQuery('.hd3'),
        hd6 = jQuery('.hd6');

    a5.hide();
    a2.hide();
    b2.hide();
    hd3.hide();
    hd6.hide();
}
```

As you can see I have to go through each one by one to hide them. Is there a way to store these into an array and just iterate through them all at once? That way if I add a new var chained query, I don't have to then go further down the function and manually hide it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try var tt = ['.a5','.a2'...]; for(var i=0,j=tt.length;i<j;i++){ $(tt[i]).hide() }

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515888/combine-two-selectors-with-one-jquery-object. You can also refer to [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give them a common class and then hide using this class as a selector that combine all those targeted elements for this operation, e.g :

```
function hideAllDivs() {
    jQuery('.common_class').hide();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a single selector:

```
jQuery('.a5, .a2, .b2, .hd3, .hd6').hide();
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider creating a new class that you apply to elements you want to hide, and just hide that single class - depends on your overall structure, but that way you don't need to come back and edit this function ever again, just apply that class where needed.